# How does RubyGems modify $PATH

Tags: bash, shell, rubygems, zsh

When you install a gem with a bin directory it is automatically added to $PATH in zsh and bash.  How does rubygems go about this without modifying your bashrc, bash_profile or anyother pre-shell script?

Comment: Really? that seems presumptuous of `gem`... does it start a new shell with the `PATH` modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you install a gem **with a bin directory** it is automatically added to $PATH in zsh and bash.

This question reads as though `$PATH` is manipulated when a gem is installed. It's not. Rather, the gem is installed *somewhere on the `$PATH`*, which is fairly common. It's my belief (which is untested), that when you install either `ruby` or `rubygems`, the `gem environment` variable `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` value (default for me is `/usr/bin`) is added to the `$PATH`, if it's not already present. However, as `/usr/bin` *should* be on the `$PATH`, this is untested conjecture, and I can't find docs to support this theory.

In my testing with `rake` (the first gem I could think of which distributes an executable), my `/usr/bin/rake` went from `version 0.8.7` to `version 0.9.2.2`. My `$PATH` wasn't touched by the `sudo gem install rake` command.

This makes sense, as RubyGems is a versioned system. It takes care of gem versions automatically, symlinking (or similar - it may be a copy-and-overwrite) the most recent version into your `$PATH` *without modifying `$PATH` itself*. I would assume that `/usr/bin/` is a common `$PATH` location.

I'm unsure what platform the OP works on. The following is relevant at least to OS X.

`gem environment`:

```
  ...SNIP...

  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin

  ...SNIP...

  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/simont/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

So, the `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` is where we'll place the executables bundled in `/bin` in the gems, and `GEM PATHS` is where we'll place the gem itself. I'm fairly sure that, if you looked in the `GEM PATHS`, you *could* find multiple versions of the same gem, including their `/bin` directories, but only the *latest* executable linked into the `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY`.

To "manually" edit the `$PATH` in the manner alluded to in the question would be platform-dependant and somewhat difficult to achieve(`bash` vs `zsh` vs `tsch` startup files, for example, and `Windows` vs `OS X` vs `Linux` vs `$OTHER_OS` environmental variables all vary quite greatly), and would also be (in my humble opinion) slightly 'rude'.

Comment: is pretty much right on. In particular though, when a gem is installed, it can either take a bin path (with the `-n` or `--bindir` option), or it will use the default, which is usually next to the `gem` executable. 

As part of installing the gem, [generate_bin is called](http://goo.gl/Mb7ri) which [creates wrapper scripts, or symlinks](http://goo.gl/An8kZ) depending on the options. 

@simont is also correct that in the chain of `GEM_PATHS`, you will find the gem cached as a `.gem` file and unpacked (including the bin directory), along with its other versions